# How to configure Spring to avoid setting Pragma No-Cache

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

My system is Spring MVC based and I checked that Spring automatically sets **PRAGMA: no-cache**. The system is available to the users through SSL. When the users try to download something using the INTERNET EXPLORER 7 or 8 an error like *"Internet Explorer cannot download file from server"* appears (more details: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q316431&).

I tried to configure the **WebContentInterceptor** like the code bellow but does not work:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2100" />
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="false" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

What can I do avoid Spring send the Pragma: no-cache and related to Cache Control?

Regards!

Comment: Did you noticed that the article you linked to, only applies for IE5 and IE6?

Comment: No, it applies for all IE's except IE 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own custom interceptor and set the header values to the response object. Interceptors are nothing but filters so override the filter and use the

> prehandle and posthandle to set the request and response headers respectively.

Let me know if you want specific examples doing that.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <beans:bean id="customInterceptor"
            class="org.example.interceptors.CustomInterceptor">
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>

</mvc:interceptors>




 public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{

     public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object arg2, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
     response.setHeader(...);}
}
```

Comment: Hi Abhi! The problem is that WebContentGenerator class creates the HTTP Headers in according with the attribute value cacheSeconds (if -1, no headders, otherwise it sets the headers). And, after they had been set, is not possible to remove them from the response...

Comment: Use HandlerInterceptor instead and the set the response in posthandle.

Comment: Hi @Abhi! I did what you suggested and I implemented the solution in preHandle method and it works! It's not a fine and clear solution but solve my issue anyway. The postHandle method does not solve because the HTTP Headers were already created when it is executed.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach is probably just to stop the header from being written with a servlet filter.  This way no Spring configuration has to be modified and you pick up the correct cache functionality for free.

```
public class PragmaFilter implements Filter {

    private static String PRAGMA_HEADER = "Pragma";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, new NoPragmaHttpServletResponseWrapper(response));
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

    private final class NoPragmaHttpServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        private NoPragmaHttpServletResponseWrapper(ServletResponse response) {
            super((HttpServletResponse) response);
        }

        @Override
        public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
            if (PRAGMA_HEADER.equals(name)) {
                return;
            }
            super.addHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            if (PRAGMA_HEADER.equals(name)) {
                return;
            }
            super.setHeader(name, value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set cache seconds to an negative value.

---

If this does not help you will need to override:

```
   protected final void preventCaching(HttpServletResponse response)
```

or

```
  protected final void applyCacheSeconds(HttpServletResponse response, int seconds, boolean mustRevalidate)
```

Both methods are implements in `WebContentGenerator`

Comment: Hi Ralph! I don't know what happens but when Spring is started, the cacheSeconds attribute of WebContentGenerator is set -1 (by default) but when the applyCacheSeconds is called the cacheSeconds is 0, calling preventCaching. And the setter method setCacheSeconds is called only once...

Comment: @Marcelo Juventino: one way how I can explain this behavior is that you "still" use the `AnnnotatopnMethodHanlder` like Tomasz suggested in his (deleted) answer, but not the `WebContentInterceptor` like you wrote in your question.

Comment: Hi @Ralph! I tried both solutions and they not resolved. Bellow, @Abhi suggested use a HandlerInterceptor and implementing the solution in the preHandler method resolved. But is not a clear and fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2100" />
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="false" />
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="false" />
        <property name="cacheMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/**/**">-1</prop><!-- removes pragma no-cache -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```